# Image gallery with bootstrap, thumbnail with bigger image

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am busy with an image gallery, using bootstrap 3.

So if I click on a image you will see the popup - which is nice of course, but the popup doesn't disappear if you click somewhere else / background - it sticks on the screen.

My code:

```
@model  ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

@*<h2>Details</h2>*@

<link href="~/Content/ShowMoreImages.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="container">

    <ul>
        <li><img src="~/Images/LCC_logo3.gif" alt="" height=150 width=200 /></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
    @*</ul>*@
</div> 



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('li img').on('click', function () {
                var src = $(this).attr('src');
                var img = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive"/>';
                $('#myModal').modal();
                $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    $('#myModal .modal-body').html(img);
                });
                $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                    $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');

                });
            });

            $("#myModal").mouseup(function (e) {
                if (e.target !== this) return;
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            });

        });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup isn't sufficient enough, would have been better if you could F12 and provide the DOM structure of that modal when its in preview mode. Looking at your code, I came up with this, added a second function to your script, called `Mouseup` on `$("#myModal")`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('li img').on('click', function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var img = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive"/>';
        $('#myModal').modal();
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myModal .modal-body').html(img);
        });
        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');

        });
    });

    $("#myModal").mouseup(function (e){
        if( e.target !== this ) return;
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });             

});


</script>
```

It will hide the modal window, if you click on the faded (outside of the modal box) part.

---

Depending on your comments, I am guessing there is something wrong in the markup itself. As in multiple elements having the same modal ID, and etc.
Take a look at 
 **[Bootstrap 3 Lightbox](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/)**
 a very detailed information, application and examples are provided, shouldn't be hard to create a gallery.

Comment: Thank you for you answare Chique, but nothing happens. But I also dont see any javascripts errors in Chrome

Comment: @Nielsfischerein Edited my code, please use it and tell me if it works.

Comment: I updated my post Chique, but the image doesnt dissapear

Comment: You have some other elements blocking over the main modal faded background, that is why I were asking about a link to your page, I need to look at the DOM structure.

Comment: yes, ok, but it is still local, I can sent you email mine is: niels.fischereinie@gmail.com

Comment: HI Chique, but what I have to sent you then?

Comment: At Chique,it is local, so how can I sent you the link then?

Comment: @Nielsfischerein You can't send a local file's link, its better if you could upload / publish it somewhere. Anyway, added another solution to my answer, take a look. Its way easier if you follow their instructions.

Comment: (At) Chique, oke, thank you. But you have some experiance in the FullCalender. I just can' t figure out. this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980974/full-calender-with-popup